# How to make one div height equal the height of another?

Tags: html, css

I want to cover up div with class main with div with class overlay. It is only working when I hardcode the height and width of overlay. This is not going to work because I am rendering multiple instances of main and they have different heights. I want to use a javascript script that will dynamically adjust the height of overlay to main.

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .22);
}

.maindiv {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <h1>
      header
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <Table class="maindiv">
    <th>adfasda</th>
    <th>adfasda</th>
    <th>adfasda</th>
    <th>adfasda</th>
    <tr>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
  </Table>
</div>
```

Comment: Its a bit unclear, do you want the overlay for maindiv or main ?

Comment: Im sorry, I want it over main

Comment: Please note  your HTML is invalid. `th` tags **must** be in `tr` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Please be clear that this is a CSS issue and not a React issue.
If you want the overlay on the main div then you can give height 100% and width 100%. This way if the main div grows, the overlay will grow with it.

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  top: 0;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <h1>header</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <table class="maindiv">
    <th>adfasda</th>
    <th>adfasda</th>
    <th>adfasda</th>
    <th>adfasda</th>
    <tr>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
      <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I want overlay to be over div main

Comment: Updated the answer to keep the overlay over the main div. However, the overlay will only cover the height of the content. Was it that you wanted to cover up the entire screen?